# Getting error while working with Task Scheduling

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks

When using laravel task scheduling, I receive the following error message:

> [ErrorException] escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons

What is the problem and how can I fix it. In addition, I haven't access to php.ini file.

Here is my code:

In Kernel:

```
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function(){
            echo "SSS";
        })->everyMinute();
    }
```

Cron job in directadmin:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /path/to/test11.txt
```

And test11.txt content:

> [ErrorException] escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons

Comment: Well, if you can't allow that function, maybe don't use it?

Comment: I've never used this function. I've written my code above, @JoelHinz

Comment: Oh, my bad. Then I'm guessing Laravel uses it and your host provider doesn't allow it... hope somebody can solve that for you.

Comment: Use `return` instead of `echo`?